# What is the traction conversion between T and H vs A and AA traction on automobile tires?

Tags: tires

I can't find in on google.  need to replace tires on Equinox LS. I looked on the side of the tire and it has Temp A Traction A. I am shoping and I find the tires are rated T and H. I haven't found consistency yet. How do I match H and T with A and AA. Not to be confused with temp A.

That being said and that being asked. I sometimes wonder what traction means since a tire that is good for one condition is not for another condition. I haven't found any that are good for dry, wet, ice, and snow and that is understandable since a tread that works for one condition may not work for another. That is why I wonder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no conversion. The [T and H are speed ratings](https://www.tirerack.com/upgrade-garage/how-do-i-check-a-tire-s-speed-rating). [A and AA are temperature and traction ratings](https://townfairtire.com/information/tire-information-guide/what-does-utqg-mean/index.shtml).

Comment: @Paulster2 Thank you !  That clears it for me. Nice article. You wouldn't happen to know off the top of your head if the AA for traction refers to all conditions in general or just a specific one like dry road?

Comment: @Sedumjoy - The traction rating is for dry asphalt or concrete. It seems as though what you're looking for is an "All Weather" tire. Most of the major brands make and sell them as such. They aren't great at any one thing, but do all of them well. Some of them do all the things *very well*.

Comment: Thank you so much. ! I will shop for all weather tires that sounds like what I need. Good in all conditions.